# separate rows based on delim based on two columns in r

Tags: r, separator

I have the following df:

```
df_1=data.frame(col_1=c("a;b;c","c;d","e","f","g","h;j"),col_2=c("1;2;3","4","5;6","7","8;9","10;11;12"))
```

so I want to separate col_1 into separate rows with corresponding values of col_2 if it exists.

1. For example if number of elements in col_1= number of elements in col_2 then they should be separated with their corresponding values in col_1 and col_2 ( row 1)
2. if they have differing number of elements, if one column has only has one element, then that can be separated to different rows as well (row 2)
3. if they have disproportionate number of elements ( more than 1 each and not equal) then it should be left as-is

here is the final_dataset:

```
df_2=data.frame(col_1=c("a","b","c","c","d","e","e","f","g","g","h;j"),col_2=c("1","2","3","4","4","5","6","7","8","9","10;11;12"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(zoo)

cnt1 <- nchar(gsub(";", "", df_1$col_1))
cnt2 <- nchar(gsub(";", "", df_1$col_2))
i1 <- cnt1 != cnt2 & cnt1 > 1 & cnt2 > 1
rbind(cSplit(df_1[!i1,], c('col_1', 'col_2'), sep=";", "long")[
          !is.na(col_1)|!is.na(col_2), lapply(.SD, na.locf0)], df_1[i1,])
#     col_1    col_2
# 1:     a        1
# 2:     b        2
# 3:     c        3
# 4:     c        4
# 5:     d        4
# 6:     e        5
# 7:     e        6
# 8:     f        7
# 9:     g        8
#10:     g        9
#11:   h;j 10;11;12
```

---

Or using `base R` with all the constraints

```
cnt1 <- nchar(gsub(";", "", df_1$col_1))
cnt2 <- nchar(gsub(";", "", df_1$col_2))
i1 <- cnt1 != cnt2 & cnt1 > 1 & cnt2 > 1
   
lst1 <- lapply(df_1[!i1, ], function(x) strsplit(x, ";"))
out <- rbind(do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) {
       l1 <- length(x)
       l2 <- length(y)
       mx <- max(l1, l2)
       x <- if(l1 != l2 &  l1 == 1) rep(x, mx) else x
       y <- if(l1 != l2 & l2 == 1) rep(y, mx) else y
       data.frame(col_1 = x, col_2 = y) } ,
       lst1[[1]], lst1[[2]])), df_1[i1,])
   
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   col_1    col_2
#1      a        1
#2      b        2
#3      c        3
#4      c        4
#5      d        4
#6      e        5
#7      e        6
#8      f        7
#9      g        8
#10     g        9
#11   h;j 10;11;12
```

Comment: thank you! except the last row, I want to keep as-is

Comment: @Mel that was confusing.  `h;j` and `10;11:12`  I thought it is h one rep and j two rep

Comment: The things is I wouldn't know about the split for this one, so it would be better to keep that as-is

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option via defining a custom function `f`

```
f <- function(v) {
  X <- unlist(strsplit(v[[1]],";"))
  Y <- unlist(strsplit(v[[2]],";"))
  if (length(X) == length(Y) || min(length(X),length(Y))==1) {
    res <- data.frame(col_1 = X, col_2 = Y)
  } else {
    res <- data.frame(col_1 = v[[1]], col_2 = v[[2]])
  }
  res
}

df_2 <- do.call(rbind,apply(df_1,1,f))
```

and we will get

```
   col_1    col_2
1      a        1
2      b        2
3      c        3
4      c        4
5      d        4
6      e        5
7      e        6
8      f        7
9      g        8
10     g        9
11   h;j 10;11;12
```